# Quarkus with RxJava support

Tags: java, reactive-programming, quarkus

I am exploring quarkus and found for Reactive programming purpose we need to use Vert.x.
Why cant we define rxjava in quarkus project pom xml and use rx.Observable as we do in a spring boot project?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Vert.x, but you don't *need* to (I guess this be read in your message as both "this is the only option in Quarkus" and "we have a good reason to prefer using Vert.x", so I'm not sure what you meant.

As for RxJava, there is support for RxJava2 as well as [whatever is supported by RESTEasy](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.4.0.Final/userguide/html/Reactive.html) (which also includes Reactor), if you're talking about REST endpoints in particular.

Do you have a more detailed use-case you can show? I'm not sure if you're talking about REST client, REST server, messaging or something else entirely.

Comment: I was referring like Observable with zip and toBlocking functions

Comment: So, yeah, `Observable` (again, assuming RxJava2) is supported out of the box, as documented by RESTEasy.